# Downloading Excel data using Axios from Laravel backend is not working

Tags: excel, reactjs, laravel, axios

I am developing a Web application using React JS for the front-end and Laravel for the back-end API. Now, what I am trying to do is I am trying to fetch the Excel data from the backend using Axios and then download the file.

This is my Laravel API controller action method.

```
function downloadExcel(Request $request)
{
    //other code goes here
    return Excel::create($left_photo->id . "-" . $right_photo->id, function($excel) use ($excel_data)
        {

            // Set the spreadsheet title, creator, and description
            $excel->setTitle('Mapping points');
            $excel->setCreator('Laravel')->setCompany('Memento');
            $excel->setDescription('Mapping points file');

            // Build the spreadsheet, passing in the payments array
            $excel->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet) use ($excel_data)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($excel_data, null, 'A1', false, false);
            });

        })->download('xlsx');
}
```

I fetch the data from the react js application using Axios like this.

```
export const getHttpClientFileDownload = (path) => {
  let accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  return Axios({
    url: getApiBaseEndpoint() + path,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob', // important
    headers : { 'api-version': API_VERSION, 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
  })
}

exportExcel()//this is the download medthod in the component
    {
        let path = 'photos/matching-points/excel?left_photo_id=' + this.props.leftImageId + "&right_photo_id=" + this.props.rightImageId;
        //let path = "curator/event/" +this.props.match.params.id + "/details";
        getHttpClientFileDownload(path)
        .then((response) => {
            alert('Everything is alright')
        })
    }
```

As you can see in the above code, if the request success, it should alert a message, "Everything is alright". But it is not alerting the message. But in the  browser, it is successful.

[image]

When I make the request to the link that is returning just normal JSON response, it is alerting the message as expected. Only it is not working as expected when I make the request to the aforementioned Excel API.

I cannot use direct download link because I am doing some authorization on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution as below.
Steps:

1. Call API to Laravel backend. Create file and store the same in local driver on server.
2. Return the file name to client.
3. Create a public route in Laravel (In web.php) to download files from Local storage. This route will delete the file after download it.
4. From client side, redirect the user to this public URL with the file name.

My code looks like this. I used fetch API.
Client side code:

```
const response = await fetch("my_server_url.com/api/createFile", {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.$store.state.AccessToken,
                        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                    },
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    console.log(response)
                    throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                window.open("my_server_url.com/downloadFile/name="+data, '_blank');
```

Code in `my_server_url.com/api/createFile` route: (api.php)

```
public function createFile()
    {
        $file_name= date('YmdHis').rand();
        Excel::store(new myExport(), $file_name.'.xlsx', 'local');

        return response()->json($file_name.'.xlsx', 200);
    }
```

Code in `my_server_url.com/downloadFile/name={file_name}` route: (web.php)

```
public function downloadFile($file_name)
    {
        return response()->download(Storage::path($file_name))->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    }
```

This way, you can check authorization and logic, but yet using the API. Also, make sure to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;` in laravel controller.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use window.open(path) to download files

Comment: I cannot use direct download link because I am doing some authorization on the server-side